# How to target exception-handling to specific exceptions?

Tags: r

Does R provide any support for targetting exception handling to only specific exceptions?

---

In Python, for example, one can narrow down exception-handling to specific exception types; e.g.:

```
try:
    return frobozz[i]
except IndexError:
    return DEFAULT
```

In this example, the exception handling will kick in only if `i` is an integer such that `i >= len(frobozz)` or `i < -len(frobozz)`, but will not catch the exception resulting from, e.g., the case where `i` is the string `"0"` (which would be a `TypeError`, rather than an `IndexError`).

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: Usually you'd implement an input check to avoid the exception.

Comment: I am not aware of a similar feature in R, but have not fully explored error handling features. A useful place to start is by reading the main help file and links linka contained in `?tryCatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wellllll...yes and no, and mostly no.

Every Python exception is wrapped in a particular error class which derives from Error, and Python modules are supposed to raise the "right" kinds of errors. For instance, an index out of range error should throw IndexError. The base language knows about these errors and so you can catch the appropriate error type in your except... clause.

R doesn't do that. Errors are untyped; there's no essential difference between an index out of bounds error and any other error.

That said, you can cheat under certain, very limited, circumstances.

```
> y <- tryCatch(x[[2]], error = function(e) e)
> y
<simpleError in x[[2]]: subscript out of bounds>
> y$message
[1] "subscript out of bounds"
```

The key here is the use of the `tryCatch` function and the `error` clause. The error clause in a tryCatch is a function of one variable which can perform arbitrary operations on e, which is an object of type 'simpleError' and contains an item named "message". You can parse message and handle interesting cases separately

```
> y <- tryCatch(x[[2]], 
  error = function(e) {
    if ('subscript out of bounds' == e$message) return(NA) else stop(e))
  })
 > y
 [1] NA
```

This only works if you can actually detect the error string you want to look for, and that isn't guaranteed. (Then again, it also isn't guaranteed in Python, so things aren't really much different from one another.)

Final question, though: why in Heaven's name are you doing this? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Just for clarity, though, that won't catch `x[['a']]`, which will still return NA. R doesn't differentiate between errors due to value type in lookups. Short of redefining the lookup operator -- which I strongly encourage you not to do! -- I can't think of a way to do that at all.